# In an Android app, where do new SQLite records get saved to in the filesystem?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to implement an Android application that uses SQLite as its data store. I am using ActiveAndroid. I have a model called Item, and I create items in the following way, calling this from the Activity's onCreate method:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.name = "test item";
item.save();
```

After launching my app, I then go to the Android Device Monitor to have access to the database files. And what I see are 2 databases in the filesystem of my app: Application.db and todoListDatabase:

[image]

Both of these databases contain a table called items, but only Application.db's version of the items table actually contains the new item records I created. Is that correct?
If this is correct, then what is the point of todoListDatabase?

**Edit**
Here are the relevant files I have:

My SQLite Helper class:

```
    public class ItemDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todoListDatabase";

    private static final String ITEMS = "items";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_BODY = "name";

    public ItemDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TODO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ITEMS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_BODY + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TODO_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion == 2) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ITEMS);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
}
```

My Item class:

```
    @Table (name = "Items")
public class Item extends Model {

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String name;

    public Item() {
        super();
    }

    public Item(String name){
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you even need a dbHelper if you use active android?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's your problem. Your ItemDatabaseHelper creates a db when your app starts, but you never even use the class.

Comment: I deleted my ItemDatabaseHelper and now I only see the Application.db created. So that's where it's stored with I use ActiveAndroid. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was using ActiveAndroid, creating a `SQLiteOpenHelper` was doing double work. That's why I was seeing 2 databases. To fix this, I deleted the `ItemDatabaseHelper` class. Then, when I go to the Android Device Monitor to see the database files, I see that Application.db is the only database there, and it has the items I created in it.

Answer (score 0):

There's just not enough information in this question, to allow it to be answered.  SQLite Databases don't just appear.  You have to create them.  Typically, you do that with a SQLiteOpenHelper.

Unless you do something odd, your database will be in the directory:

```
/data/data/<your application's package name>/databases
```

For example, a database for the Google mail application might be:

```
/data/data/com.google.android.gm/databases/mail.db
```

Comment: I have added the relevant files.